# For multiple hypothesis testing, what does it mean to assume that the distribution of p‐values is “correct”?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons

For multiple hypothesis testing, I've often read, without significant detail, that we must assume the distribution of p‐values is “correct”. I am wondering what this means. Does it mean the p-values are uniform under the null? Is that the only condition?